# Inconvenient working time mysql between reported hours

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, datetime

I trying to build a function that checks for inconvenient time to calculate salary that day.

The user inputs that he has ben working between

16:00 and 02:00

Now I need to check if he had worked inconvenient time.

> ```
> Between 06:00 - 17:59 Normal time (salary $100)
> level 1 18:00 - 00:00 (salary $140)
> level 2 00:01 - 0600 (salary  $200)
> ```

The report should say

> ```
> Normal time 2 hour
> Level1 6 hour
> Level2 2 hour
> ```

Is there a smart way to check this using MySQL or JavaScript? Maybe you can point me to a article or something. I have bean searching for a solution for a long time now.

Best regards

Martin

Comment: I don't see any need for a database here.  Why not just do this logic in javascript?  Or, do you have a table of such times and you want to do this for many users and or many days?  If so, show the layout of the table and provide sample data.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is create event trigger! 
**Table hours worked :**

```
col1 worker_id
col2 hours
col3 hour_type
```

Create a trigger that will choose your hour type. So by doing that when ever you insert an worked hour it will be calculated depending on the time is was inserted ! 
does this makes sense ?